# How come my page navigation with ScrollTo() is not on the right page? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm working on my portfolio at the moment and I am using the ScrollTo jQuery plugin to let the visitors navigate through the pages. I got that all working but I also wanted to implement a link with which you can scroll from one page to the other, like a prev next page, and that has to be different on every page.

I also got that working but somehow it shows the wrong links on the wrong pages.
For example: page 2 has the links of page 1, page 3 has the links of page 2.
And when you click on that link again, then the links will change to the right ones.

You can check it out here: http://machimedia.nl/portfolio/

This is the function I used:

```
function reloadPageNav(){
var section1Top =  0;
// The top of each section is offset by half the distance to the previous section.
var section2Top =  $('#portfolio').offset().left - (($('#aboutme').offset().left - $('#portfolio').offset().left) / 2);
var section3Top =  $('#aboutme').offset().left - (($(document).width() - $('#aboutme').offset().left) / 2);;

if($(document).scrollTop() >= section1Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section2Top){
    $('nav#homenav').delay(1000).fadeIn(800);
} else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section2Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section3Top){
    $('nav#portfolionav').delay(1000).fadeIn(800);
} else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section3Top){
    $('nav#aboutmenav').delay(1000).fadeIn(800);
} }
```

And it is called when a.link is clicked, so that whenever a link is clicked the pagenav will be redrawn. I used the following function for this.

```
$('a.link').click(function () {  
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 1500);
    //setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud1', '0px', '400px', '800px', '1200px')
    //setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud2', '0px', '800px', '1600px', '2400px')
    $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    $('nav.next').fadeOut(500);
    $('nav.prev').fadeOut(500);
    reloadPageNav();
    homeNav();
    return false;  

});
```

Hopefully any of you can help me with this problem and sort it out for me.
Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Comment: Where do you reset the href of nav.next and nav.prev?  I can't find it?  Wouldn't that have to happen somewhere?  Am I looking at that wrong?

Comment: When a.link is clicked the nav.prev and nav.next fadeout.
And when scrollto is at a certain width of the page, the correct menu must load. But it loads the wrong one some how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I see one thing, but I'm not sure if it will fix everything.

Change your click event handler to this code below.  The way you have your reloadPageNav function set up, you are assuming that you have already scrolled to the new location.  But the scrollTo will run async... so it probably won't be done by that time.  In the code below, you move the reloadPageNav to a callback function of scrollTo... so it won't be called until the scrolling is done.

```
$('a.link').click(function () {  
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 1500, {onAfter: function(){reloadPageNav();}});
    $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    $('nav.next').fadeOut(500);
    $('nav.prev').fadeOut(500);
    homeNav();
    return false;  

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not work though, but it is also good to improve it.

It now still has the menu on the wrong page.. 
I guess is must have something to do with the reloadPageNav function

Comment: did you make this change on the site?  I got shut down right now, but I'll mess around with it tonight.

Comment: Yes I did. But i changed the location of the nav.next and nav.pref fadeOut() in the function, because otherwise it would reload the nav and after that fadeOut the nav..

you can check the full code here:
http://machimedia.nl/portfolio/index.html
http://machimedia.nl/portfolio/js/javascript.js
 and thanks for your help ;)

Comment: oh... I apparently don't know the ScrollTo plugin very well.  That third option is for all options, not just a call back.  I've updated my answer.  Can you add that to the code?